# How to make an AddComponent like the Unity system?

Tags: c#

So, I kind of trying to make my own implementation of `AddComponent` in Unity but for SDL2-CS, I did most of the things except adding the component.

I would store the components in a list like this

```cs
private List<Component> components = new List<Component>();
public T AddComponent<T>()
{
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(Component)){
        Component component = (Component)Convert.ChangeType(typeof(T), typeof(Component));
        components.Add(component);
        return (T)component;
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

Although, this obviously doesn't work since I can't just convert component into T but I can't find anymore documentation for it.
I tried compiling it and, this is the error.

```
Cannot convert type 'SDL2.Component' to 'T'
```

Does anyone have any workaround for this thing?
Also, everything that will be sent to the `AddComponent` will be inheriting `Component`.

**EDIT:**

Now I kind of found a way! Thanks to [Fabjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4995012/fabjan) for the recommendation.

```cs
private List<Component> components = new List<Component>();
public T AddComponent<T>()
{
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    var component = (Component)instance;
    components.Add(component);
    return (T)instance;
}
```

Comment: If everything inherits from Component, then why do you need generics at all?

Comment: Because it need to return that type, not what it inherits

Comment: You're trying to add a `Type` to `List<Component>`

Comment: @Fabjan Well, yes. Do I need to use another? If so tell me since I have no idea

Comment: Instead of `Convert.ChangeType` try using `Activator.CreateInstance`

Comment: @Fabjan Oki, well then how do I return the instance back?
- I found a bit of answers so I'll experiment some more with stuff

Comment: yeah well, I need to mess around with a lot of stuff but at least it's worth it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Convert.ChangeType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=net-6.0) is not meant to create new objects, use [Activator.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=net-6.0) instead.**

---

A runtime approach can verify inheritance at runtime:

```
public T AddComponent<T>()
{
    if(typeof(Component).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))){
        var component = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        components.Add(component as Component);
        return component;
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

But you can have a better approach which makes the test at compile time:

```
public T AddComponent<T>() where T : Component
{
    var component = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    components.Add(component);
    return component;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know determining the base class was possible. Haha